# Как правильно использовать редьюсеры в redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Вот редьюсер через который я перезаписываю стор:

```
export default function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_TASK') {
    let newTask = new TaskItem();
    let output = {
      data: {
        ongoing: [
          newTask,
          ...state.data.ongoing,
        ],
        completed: [
          ...state.data.completed,
        ],
      },
      settings: state.settings,
    };
    console.log(state);
    return output;
  }
  return state;
}
```

Вроде как в документации такой способ указан как верный, однако мне кажется, что я делаю что-то не правильно, так как при сложноструктурированном сторе объект для обновления одной записи, придется переписывать всю сложную структуру.

Как правильно обновлять данные в сторе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никакой логики не должно быть в редюсере. Редюсер это чистая функция без сайд эффектов только положить, достать, удалить. Всю логику нужно выносить в другое место, напрмер в [`middelware`](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) такие как [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga). Для сложных структур с большой вложенностью можно использовать вспомогательные библиотеки [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr). Это большая и очень веселая тема )

```
import { ADD_TASK, TASK_LOADING } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  errors: [],
  isLoading: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [action.item, ...state.items],
        isLoading: false,
      };

    case TASK_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };

    /* another cases... */

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```